# System.IO.FileNotFoundException with Log4Net when released

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, log4net, advanced-installer

In a C# app, we have configured Log4Net in an attempt to log unexpected exceptions. Logging works as expected when run from Visual Studio, but the app crashes when installed with Active Installer and run on a client.

**Log4Net configuration:**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="MyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Temp\MyApp\log.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

**Usage:**

```
// in App : Application
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
// in Main()
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log.Info("Log initialised");
```

**The app crashes with exception**

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord, System.Reflection.MetadataImport, System.Reflection.Assembly ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Object[], System.Collections.IList, System.RuntimeType ByRef, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Boolean, System.Collections.IList, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(System.Type, Boolean)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type, Boolean)
   at System.AppDomain.GetTargetFrameworkName()
```

We have also attempted other options for the  field, but without luck.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: What does the `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` property return? Does your application have the access right to write in the temp folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have copied the log4net dlls when you have installed the application, just check if you have the same files on the client als you have on your development machine.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, but unfortunately that is not what is causing the crash mentioned in the question

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the log4net dlls when you have installed the application, just check if you have the same files on the client als you have on your development machine.

Comment: You were right, Peter! I was missing a dll. I'm happy to accept an answer if you create one :-)